# Problem compiling program with pqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, g++, libpqxx

I'm trying to compile a very simple program (sample that does nothing) with pqxx, but cannot do it.
Here's the 'program':

$ cat xx.cpp

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
using namespace pqxx;


int main() 
{
    connection conn("dbname=dout1");
    return 0;
}
```

The command I used to try to compile in C++:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -l pqxx -I /opt/postgres_home/include/ -L /opt/postgres_home/lib/ -lpq xx.cpp
```

Message returned:

```
/tmp/cc18wMEy.o: In function `pqxx::connect_direct::connect_direct(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx14connect_directC1ERKSs[pqxx::connect_direct::connect_direct(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x1f): undefined reference to `pqxx::connectionpolicy::connectionpolicy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx14connect_directC1ERKSs[pqxx::connect_direct::connect_direct(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x2a): undefined reference to `vtable for pqxx::connect_direct'
/tmp/cc18wMEy.o: In function `pqxx::connect_direct::~connect_direct()':
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx14connect_directD1Ev[pqxx::connect_direct::~connect_direct()]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for pqxx::connect_direct'
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx14connect_directD1Ev[pqxx::connect_direct::~connect_direct()]+0x1f): undefined reference to `pqxx::connectionpolicy::~connectionpolicy()'
/tmp/cc18wMEy.o: In function `pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::basic_connection(char const*)':
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx16basic_connectionINS_14connect_directEEC1EPKc[pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::basic_connection(char const*)]+0x2b): undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::connection_base(pqxx::connectionpolicy&)'
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx16basic_connectionINS_14connect_directEEC1EPKc[pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::basic_connection(char const*)]+0xd6): undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::init()'
/tmp/cc18wMEy.o: In function `pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::~basic_connection()':
xx.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx16basic_connectionINS_14connect_directEED1Ev[pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::~basic_connection()]+0x17): undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::close()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I do like:

```
$ g++ -I /usr/local/include/pqxx -L /usr/local/lib/ -l pqxx -l pq xx.cpp
```

Returns:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.4.4/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Considering:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf

/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/pgsql/lib                <-- just symlink to /opt/postgres_home/
/opt/postgres_home/lib
/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/lib
/usr/lib64/seamonkey
/opt/kde3/lib64
/usr/lib64/jre1.6.0_16/lib/amd64
```

I really don't know what else to do, because:

```
 # ls /opt/postgres_home/lib/libpq*                                                      
/opt/postgres_home/lib/libpq.a     /opt/postgres_home/lib/libpq.so.5.3
/opt/postgres_home/lib/libpq.so    /opt/postgres_home/lib/libpqwalreceiver.so
/opt/postgres_home/lib/libpq.so.5
```

Luis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After  an email exchange with pqxx author Jeroen T. Vermeulen, I could manage to compile the 'program'.
The idea was to place `xx.cpp` before `-lpqxx -lpq`
So, the entire command is:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/pqxx/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -I /usr/local/pgsql/include/ -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib/ xx.cpp -lpqxx  -lpq
```

It works now.

Comment: Even I get the undefined reference and in my case I'm using code::blocks. do you have a fix or some idea about it?

Comment: What happens if you use g++?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me here with a simple g++ -lpqxx xx.cpp, so it terribly looks like a broken installation. Note that you don't need to link with libpq, as libpqxx with take care of that for you if you are using shared objects.

Check that you don't have the libpqxx library installed in different places, like /usr/lib, /usr/local, and /usr/local/pgsql/lib.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem was not the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to *link* to both libpqxx and libpq (in that order).  You just don't need the libpq *headers* while compiling your own code.

In the original post, it's actually libpq that's missing.  It's probably just in an unexpected location.