# How to solve this compiling error with pqxx under code blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

After using libpq-fe.h in the past, for a new project I'm starting use pqxx.

So, in the code I include:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
```

And I compile. Everything fine.

When I declare:

```
pqxx::connection p_con;
```

And I compile, I have errors:

```
obj/Debug/src/dbfunc.o: In function `pqxx::connect_direct::connect_direct(std::string const&)':
/usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx:87: undefined reference to `pqxx::connectionpolicy::connectionpolicy(std::string const&)'
/usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx:87: undefined reference to `vtable for pqxx::connect_direct'
obj/Debug/src/dbfunc.o: In function `pqxx::connect_direct::~connect_direct()':
/usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx:84: undefined reference to `vtable for pqxx::connect_direct'
/usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx:84: undefined reference to `pqxx::connectionpolicy::~connectionpolicy()'
obj/Debug/src/dbfunc.o: In function `pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::basic_connection()':
/usr/include/pqxx/basic_connection.hxx:61: undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::connection_base(pqxx::connectionpolicy&)'
/usr/include/pqxx/basic_connection.hxx:62: undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::init()'
obj/Debug/src/dbfunc.o: In function `pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::~basic_connection()':
/usr/include/pqxx/basic_connection.hxx:78: undefined reference to `pqxx::connection_base::close()'
```

A search on google indicates that this is not a library problem. 

Infact: a very similar problem, same error, was already solved here: [Problem compiling program with pqxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289307/problem-compiling-program-with-pqxx)

**I don't get how to solve it in code::blocks. Any suggestion?**

Software versions:

- Code::Blocks 13.12
- Os: Debian 8.2
- Libpqxx: libpqxx-4.0
- Compiler used: gcc
- gcc --version: gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

I am relatively new to using code::blocks, so probably I'm missing something :-/

**EDIT**: As requested the 2 path:

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**libpq.so**
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**libpq.a**

Comment: you're compiling with `-lpq` right?

Comment: No, i didn't. I added it in project-> build options -> Compiler settings  -> other options But nothing changes. Well, the command change: "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -g -lpq -Iinclude -c /myfile.cpp -o /myfile.o"

Comment: first try Mike Kinghan suggestion if unsuccessful search for a file named `libpq.so` or `libpq.a` on your system and post its path

Comment: Ok, I have both. Paths inserted in question.

Comment: now add `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpq` in linker settings

Comment: In meantime Mike found what I made wrong. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lpq`, like all `-l<libname>` options, is a linker option, not
a compiler option. By putting it in **Compiler settings** -> **Other options**
you say you have generated a compile commandline:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -g -lpq -Iinclude -c /myfile.cpp -o /myfile.o
```

Since this is just a *compile* command no linking is involved and `-lpq` is ignored,
while in your *link* commandline - which you haven't shown us - no `-lpq` option
will appear.

Take `-lpq` out of **Compiler settings** -> **Other options** and put `-lpqxx` and `-lpq`
in **Linker settings** -> **Other options**. Then `-lpqxx -lpq` will be passed to
to linker, as they need to be.

If the linker complains that `-lpqxx` is not found, then you need to install
`libpqxx`

Comment: Made modifications as you indicated,but error still remains.

Comment: @user_0 Still missing the right library! See update.

Comment: Well, I need to admit, I'm a bit rusty, after years, return to c++. Thank you for your correction. Everything fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user_0 Well it was dumb of of me to overlook `xx` to start with!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

try declaring the connection to a unique pointer:

`std::unique_ptr<pqxx::connection> connection;`

then you can pass it in to a function like:

```
bool do_something(std::unique_ptr<pqxx::connection> & connection) {

    connection.reset(new pqxx::connection("myconnectionstring"));

    std::string sqlstr ="select * from some table;";

    pqxx::result r;
    try {
        pqxx::work query(*connection, "");
        r = query.exec(sqlstr, "cache batch types");

    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        return false;
    }

    // handle results...

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Still get: /usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx|84|undefined reference to `vtable for pqxx::connect_direct'|    AND    /usr/include/pqxx/connection.hxx|84|undefined reference to `pqxx::connectionpolicy::~connectionpolicy()'|

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error the OP described when switching from vim to Code::Blocks.

I solved it by putting "pqxx" under 'Settings/Compiler and debugger settings" on the tab "Linker settings" in the left-hand pane ("Link libraries").

After that, my program (which uses the pqxx lib) compiled without errors.

I'm using Code::Blocks 10.05 on Linux Mint 13 Maya.